# Java: Optimized Large Scale Value Storage Alternatives

Tags: java, mongodb, optimization, duplicates, web-crawler

I am working on a web crawler / spider and I need some way to efficiently mass store strings as a reference for (1) already stored sites and (2) a queue for my crawler. These storage data structures must be able to hold well beyond millions of string values. I will start with the research I have researched and what I have done respectively.

The first method I tried was referenced from this thread

> [Java: optimize hashset for large-scale duplicate detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693408/java-optimize-hashset-for-large-scale-duplicate-detection)

In this thread, the OP talks about optimizing a HashSet and was given a lot of good feedback and warning. A HashSet was very expensive to use and caused my program to crash very quickly. In the replies, alternatives like Trove was suggested, however the project has since been discontinued and I believe there are better alternatives.

The second method I tried was to create a queue using MongoDB. I created a collection explicitly for a queue where I followed FIFO as Mongo uses locks so it should be thread safe. And from what I could tell, it worked very well. My crawler was running very well and used very little amount of memory (12~42MB) on average. However this method soon proved to be very poor as MongoDB has a search speed of o(n). Having created an iterator that checks two collections (website collection and queue collection) per single website to-be cached proved to be very detrimental.

Having followed this thread

> [Strategies for fast searches of billions of small documents in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752597/strategies-for-fast-searches-of-billions-of-small-documents-in-mongodb)

It did improve the search quality slightly, but it was a mild offset. Below is a simple pseudo code of my web crawler.

```
while(true){
    parse();
}

public void parse(){
    String next = // next url in queue to be parsed
    Document document = // get HTML dom from next url

    // store document inside of site storage (mongo collection)
    // grab links from document

    for( all links found ) {
        if(next doesn't exist in website collection and next isn't already in queue){
            add to queue 
        }
    }

}
```

The check for "next doesn't exist in website collection and next isn't already in queue", I have to create an iterator or use mongo.collection.find().limit(1) (which is also an iterator, just behind the scenes) to check if the next element exists inside of the current stored websites or the queue. So as you can see, as the two collections grow, currently with over 100,000 entries in both, it can be very expensive and slow for the processor to constantly check both collections.

Which brings me be back to my first method, which is holding potentially up to billions URLs in memory for faster searching for duplicates in both storages. A majority of the things I read were very useful but are out dated and I was wondering what you guys thought the best method for this is?

Answer (score 0):

> holding potentially up to billions URLs in memory

This is surely something you needn't and should not do.

> I have to create an iterator

This is surely something you must not do (unless the iterator runs only over a tiny fraction of your data).

---

> next doesn't exist in website collection and next isn't already in queue

Think about data representation. For searching, lists are far too slow, so you need an indexed search. Something like `HashMap` or `TreeMap`, but on the disk.

I know close to nothing about MongoDB, but every database worth its name can do this. I guess, it works already with your *collection*, just the *queue* is a problem. The queue is more complicated as you need both a fast search and the queue-ness.

This problem can be eliminated trivially by putting every new element into both the *queue* and the *collection*, so you only need to check the collection for duplicates (which IIUYC can you do pretty fast). Obviously, you need a marker to distinguish elements not yet fetched.

---

A next optimization would be keeping a cache of a few recently accessed elements in memory, so that some repeated DB queries could be eliminated. I'd bet, a Bloom Filter could help, too.

---

You can also use a real `Map` on the disk: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map